# Java, Azure select database row via user input

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I select a row from an Azure database table using user input for the where clause. For example:

```
final MobileServiceList<NewsfeedItems> result = mToDoTable.where().field("location").eq(county).execute().get();
```

In the above line of code, county is a variable for a string. But this line searches for the string county instead of searching for the county variable value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you initialize the String *county* ? In the same function/method ? If you did not initialize it in the same function it is possible that the variable can not be resolved (reference) and so *county* is not treated as a variable but as a string.

In the **.eq**-function it is possible to insert a String variable and a string itself.

If a variable is inserted and can not be resolved because it is not local (or a class variable) the input in the .eq-function is processed as a string.

As a test create a variable *county* in the same function and initialize it with a particular value that appears in the database like

```
    private void searchContact(View view) {
    String name = newContactName.getText().toString();
    // Search for the contact based on the name field
    mobileContactTable.where().field("name").eq(name).execute(...
    }
```

and then run the code again

Comment: county is initialized right after I initialize my class. It is then assigned a string value within the onCreate

Comment: This will not work (encapsulation). To use the same variable in multiple methods see this http://www.coderanch.com/t/519019/java/java/variables-multiple-methods (declare static, create instance,...)

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a mill!!